# Store Google Drive Access Token in Database in Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api, store, access-token

how to store access token after authentication in google Drive And please tell me how to auto refresh token if it is expired.
please provide example of it.
in my Web Application it stores Token in %AppData% Folder but i want to store in Sql Server database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't store the access token as it only lives for one hour. If you really really want to store it anyway (maybe as a kind of keepsake) it's just a simple string so store it as you would any other string. The thing you should be storing is the refresh token, which is also just a string.

Comment: Can you please provide some code for it? to Refresh token whenever it expires ?

Comment: if you want a code sample to teach you how to save a string to a SQL Server database, then either ask that as a new question with a SQL Server tag, or hire a developer from freelancer.com to do it for you. The refresh token doesn't expire.

Comment: I am not asking a code to store string in db. I am asking that Google creates its access token in %webapps% folder so other than that i want to store token in db.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the refresh to SQL database.
As far as i know you can use this refresh token when the access token expires.
There are two ways to handle refresh tokens:
1. Create a service that checks all the access token and refresh ones that are due to expire.
2. Or request a new access token using refresh token whenever you get an access token expiry error from the server during api calls. And then request the  same api call once the access token is managed.

I am not sure if these are the best ways to handle refresh token.
Also my other question is whether it is common to store the access token. Or are we supposed to just authorise and get new access token every time we make api calls.

Any recommendations and experiences would be really appreciated.

Cheers.